# guava LoadingCache.refresh - why do we need it if we can just Cache.invalidate?

Tags: java, caching, guava

Using guava - why do we need `LoadingCache.refresh`?
Can't we just use `Cache.invalidate` and on our next `get` the value would be refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics are:

- `LoadingCache.refresh`: The existing mapping is still present and the cache continues to return the stored value until the new value is available
- `Cache.invalidate`: The mapping discarded. A new value would be loaded upon the next `LoadingCache.get()`

If your application uses `LoadingCache.get()` there may be no "logic" difference between both. If (maybe lots) of concurrent requests happen, then the application will behave differently:

- With `LoadingCache.refresh` the application will constantly serve requests. The loader response time does not effect the application response time.
- With `LoadingCache.get()`, requests might block until the loading is completed. This might get dangerous, for example, lets say there are 1000 requests per second and your loading takes 5 seconds. That would mean that 5000 requests would be blocked and are waiting for the response. If one application request depends on multiple caches and loaders, this might be even worse.
- However, with `LoadingCache.refresh` you are still serving an possibly outdated value. You cannot use it if you need consistency

Main take away:

If not refreshed concurrently the load times add to your application response time and worsen the user experience.